# Send a javascript var to my model in FTL

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, freemarker, magnolia

I have a list of checkboxes, with this function i get my array of checked items:

```
 var selected = new Array(); 
 $('#bloqCountries input:checked').each(function() { selected.push($(this).val()); });
```

I have a model class and i need to send by parameter this array making something like this:

```
 [#assign searchResults =model.searchContent(selected) /]
```

But Javascript is in client side and Freemarker in server side...

Then i don´t know how to get this array in my model to call my modelClass..

My idea is making by the request, transforming the array in string and making a split() method in java to delete the "-" between the words

I don't know how to send this content because i´m not using ajax and I don't think its necessary.

Comment: Can you not serialize (JSON.stringify(selected)) the array and send it to your server via ajax? Then you decode the JSON on the server and you have a native array (whatever that is in Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't do that. FTL template is executed on the server and only once, to produce HTML and to send it to browser. JS is executed only when browser receives and processes said HTML. By that time, FTL process is long dead.

If you want to communicate with the server, ajax is the only way to do that. You might find some inspiration and examples of using ajax w/ Magnolia at [here](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blogs/tomas-gregovsky/detail~@webinar-retrospective--building-modern-responsive-sites-quickly-with-magnolia~.html) or [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Accessing+content+on+the+client+side).

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks bro, i made a call to my model in the javascript´s script cause Ftl syntaxt is soported